# How can I include try: and except: for exception handling?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, try-catch

I attempted to include `try:` and `except:` in this program to catch text string exceptions, but unable to figure out how to implement. How can I include `try:` and `except:` for exception handling?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

h = float(raw_input('Enter Hours: '))
r = float(raw_input('Enter Rate: '))
if h > 40 :
    p = h * r + (h - 40) * r * 0.5
else :
    p = h * r
print 'Pay:', p
```

Comment: [Error handling in python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

def calc_pay(h, r) :
    if h <= 0 or r <= 0 :
        return None
    elif h > 40 :
        return (h * r + (h - 40) * r * 0.5)
    else :
        return (h * r)

try :
    h = float(raw_input('Enter Hours: '))
    r = float(raw_input('Enter Rate: '))
    p = calc_pay(h, r)
    print 'Pay:', p
except :
    print "Enter Numeric Data"
```

Comment: Since `raw_input` is where I would trigger an error message (for example, if I were to enter a text string at a prompt) the calculation function was not included within the `try` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a try except pair

```
def num(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except :
        return None
h = num(raw_input('Enter Hours: '))
```

Now you need to ask for a valid response. for example.

```
h = None
p = None
while (h is None):
    h = num(raw_input('Enter Hours: '))
while (p is None):
    p = num(raw_input('Enter Price: '))
```

This depends on how you want to handle the rest of the processing. Some might prefer to return a 0 if it is an invalid entry since 0 price or 0 hours would also be invalid so test for > 0

```
def num(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except :
        return 0.0
h = num(raw_input('Enter Hours: '))

h = 0.0
p = 0.0
while (h <= 0.0):
    h = num(raw_input('Enter Hours: '))
while (p <= 0.0):
    p = num(raw_input('Enter Price: '))
```

Comment: Returning `None` just pushed the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Holloway The point is that after you return the None, you need to do a if test (or a while) to handle the error

Comment: exactly. If you're going to do a check on the return value anyway, you might as well have handled the problem where it happened.

Comment: @Holloway Yes but in this way, you do not need to repeat the try except pair for the price as well.

Comment: You should use `is` when comparing to `None`.